# Visual Studio 2013 In Windows Vista

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

Im trying to install Visual Studio 2013 in my laptop with windows Vista but it tells me that i dont have an appropiate system can i install this version (VS 2013) in windows vista? i already have VS 2008 & 2010

Comment: If you don't have an appropriate system, you can't. And you should really update Windows Vista to Seven or buy a new laptop. Is very recommendable. About the application, Windows vista may have an incompatible architecture thus this doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with @wonderwhy, you shouldn't be using windows vista.

Comment: I know but im studying at the middle of semester and I cannot update to 7 and then reinstall all programas and extensions to study :/